# Loading neo4j nodes with nearest neighbours in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

In my project an object `User` has a collection of `Item` items, with which it is related by a one-to-many "OWNS" relationship. Each item
is related back to the user with a one-to-one "OWNED_BY" relationship.
My (shortened) classes look like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {
    . . .
    @Relationship(type="OWNS", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Collection<Item> items;
    . . .
}

@NodeEntity
public class Item {
    . . .
    @Relationship(type="OWNED_BY", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    public User owner;
    . . .
}
```

I store the nodes using a user and item repository
(example):

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends Neo4jRepository<User, Long> {
    . . .
    @Query("MATCH (user:User) WHERE ID(user)={0} RETURN user")
    User getById(Long id);
    . . .
}
```

simply by populating the Collection with a setter and saving with the default `save()` method.

```
User user = ...
user.setItems(. . .);
userRepository.save(user);
```

And everything works well. The data persists in the graph along with all corresponding relationships.
Spring data docs states that "By default, loading an instance 
will map that object’s simple properties and its immediately-related objects (i.e. depth = 1)."
Which is exactly what I want.
This however does not happen when I attempt to get the data back.

Getting a User using:

```
User user = userRepository.getById(id);
```

Does indeed return the correct User but it's relationship to the items (Collection items) is null.

As a sidenote I am using spring boot and my dependencies are these:

```
    dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j:2.0.3.RELEASE')
    //compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:5.0.8.RELEASE')
    compile('org.neo4j:neo4j:3.4.3')
    compile('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core:3.1.0')
    runtime('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-http-driver:3.1.0')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.0.3.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.0.3.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.0.3.RELEASE')
    compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:3.0.2.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.3.RELEASE')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22')
    compile('junit:junit:4.12')
    }
```

Why is this happening? How can I get all immidiate neighbours when loading a given node (load depth=1 which should be the default)?

Edit: I have fallen back to using the provided Neo4jRepository  findById(id, depth) But I still can't figure out how to make it work with my own queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really add a depth from Spring when using custom queries.
Instead include the depth in the custom query itself.
For example let's assume that you have a linked list of messages:

```
(:Message{id:1})-[:NEXT]->(:Message{id:2})-[:NEXT]->(:Message{id:3})
                                          \
                                           \-[:ATTACHMENT]->(:Image{id:4})
```

You can get the closest neighbors by specifying the desired root node along with the path length like this:

```
MATCH (m:Message)-[*0..0]-(a) where ID(m)=1 RETURN *
```

The above will return only the root node.

```
MATCH (m:Message)-[*0..1]-(a) where ID(m)=1 RETURN *
MATCH (m:Message)-[*0..2]-(a) where ID(m)=1 RETURN *
```

The above will return:

```
(:Message{id:1})-[:NEXT]->(:Message{id:2})
```

and

```
(:Message{id:1})-[:NEXT]->(:Message{id:2})-[:NEXT]->(:Message{id:3})
                                      \
                                       \-[:ATTACHMENT]->(:Image{id:4})
```

respectively.

Modify your query to look like this:

```
@Query("MATCH (user:User)-[p:OWNS*0..1]->(item:Item) WHERE user.username={0} RETURN *")
User getByUsernameWithItems(String username);
```

The above will return the user and the `Collection<Item> items` will be populated with the first level neighbouring Item nodes.